# Modifying LinkedListNode property in C#

Tags: c#, list, properties, linked-list

I'm working with LinkedList in C#.
All I want to do is a simple code that excludes B from the list and directly connect node A with B.Next:

```
A.Next = B.Next;
B.Next.Previous = A;
```

But got an error:

> Property or indexer System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<>.Next
>   cannot be assigned to it is read only.

Is it possible to somehow get the right to assign values to Next and Previos properties?
Or how can I avoid this error?
Best regards.

Answer (score 5):

You can just call [`LinkedList<T>.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43ttx77w.aspx) and pass in `B`.  The [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43ttx77w.aspx) method takes care of this for you.